# Why does it take so much time for compiling verilog HDL code in Quartus?

Tags: verilog, aes

I am writing a verilog code in Quartus to encrypt AES-128bit.Every sub-module works well but when I compile the main module, it take more than 2 hours to complete with no error. Especially, when i change an important line of code (the result is wrong but the work flow of the code is not changed), it can be compiled in 5 seconds. It is so weird.

Here is the code that run in 2 hours:

```
module AES_Encrypt#(parameter N=128,parameter Nr=10,parameter Nk=4)(in,key,out);
input [127:0] in;
input [N-1:0] key;
output [127:0] out;
wire [(128*(Nr+1))-1 :0] fullkeys;
wire [127:0] states [Nr+1:0] ;
wire [127:0] afterSubBytes;
wire [127:0] afterShiftRows;
genvar i;

keyExpansion #(Nk,Nr) ke (key,fullkeys);

addRoundKey addrk1 (in,states[0],fullkeys[((128*(Nr+1))-1)-:128]);

generate
    for(i=1;i<Nr;i=i+1) begin: loop
        encryptRound er(states[i-1],fullkeys[(((128*(Nr+1))-1)-128*1)-:128],states[i]);
    end
endgenerate
    
subBytes sb(states[Nr-1],afterSubBytes);
shiftRows sr(afterSubBytes,afterShiftRows);
addRoundKey addrk2(afterShiftRows,states[Nr],fullkeys[127:0]); 
assign out=states[Nr];//This is the code that I will change
    
endmodule
```

And here is the code that run in 5 seconds:

```
module AES_Encrypt#(parameter N=128,parameter Nr=10,parameter Nk=4)(in,key,out);
input [127:0] in;
input [N-1:0] key;
output [127:0] out;
wire [(128*(Nr+1))-1 :0] fullkeys;
wire [127:0] states [Nr+1:0] ;
wire [127:0] afterSubBytes;
wire [127:0] afterShiftRows;
genvar i;

keyExpansion #(Nk,Nr) ke (key,fullkeys);

addRoundKey addrk1 (in,states[0],fullkeys[((128*(Nr+1))-1)-:128]);

generate
    for(i=1;i<Nr;i=i+1) begin: loop
        encryptRound er(states[i-1],fullkeys[(((128*(Nr+1))-1)-128*1)-:128],states[i]);
    end
endgenerate
    
subBytes sb(states[Nr-1],afterSubBytes);
shiftRows sr(afterSubBytes,afterShiftRows);
addRoundKey addrk2(afterShiftRows,states[Nr],fullkeys[127:0]); 
assign out=1; //Here it is
    
endmodule
```

The only differences between 2 RTL designs is the output.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that if you assign a constant to the only output of a module, all of the rest of the logic inside the module becomes irrelevant?

Comment: Besides which, is that a typo in line 17? Should `-128*1` be `-128*i`?

Comment: 2hrs is nothing in the world of FPGAs. Big designs take a long time to process.

Answer (score 1):

By assigning a constant to the output, you're making all of the other code in the module unused. The logic optimizer in Quartus will of course remove all of the unused logic, leaving you with what is essentially an empty module.

You have to keep in mind that building a HDL design is totally different from compiling software. Your design is not being turned into instructions for a processor, but rather into logic circuits. Essentially, your design *is the processor*, and Quartus needs some time to build that processor for you.

With the way you've built your HDL module, you're telling Quartus to make a gigantic logic circuit that performs all of the AES encryption steps in parallel. Every single operation in the AES encryption will be synthesized down to its own logic circuits, which of course results in a gigantic piece of logic that likely fills a significant portion of the FPGA's resources.

You might want to consider building a clocked multi-cycle AES encryption unit instead, which doesn't perform all steps massively in parallel using ridiculous amounts of hardware, but instead re-uses the same hardware to perform one step at a time. That of course means you'll need a clock signal, registers, and state machines to control the operations.

Alternatively, you could look into high-level synthesis tools. Depending on the level of abstraction you want, you could build your design in a C-based HLS suite, or maybe go for a slightly lower-level approach with Bluespec SystemVerilog.

Comment: Yep if you design FPGAs you learn that unexpectedly fast compilation means you messed something important up.  Probably a botched assignment, clock or reset.

Answer (score 0):

> The only differences between 2 RTL designs is the output.

In the second version of the code which uses `assign out=1` the HDL compiler will be able to eliminate the other expressions since they have no side effect on the output.

While the first version of the code, can Quartus actually place it into the device or  does the amount of logic exceed the size of the device?

Based upon the other [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/689635/101063)  possibly not.